# Can a .Net namespaces span multiple assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, .net-assembly

Can a .Net namespaces span multiple assemblies? Specific examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Eg. `System` is, some of it is in `mscorlib.dll`, other parts are in `System.dll` and `System.Core.dll` (and, I assume, others).

Comment: And there's nothing stopping you writing your own assembly in the System namespace!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
And this is the right approach to separate different logic parts of your application.

YourApp.Dal - separate assembly with data access layer.

YourApp.Infrastructure - separate assembly with some infrastructure.

YourApp.Web - web part of your application.