# Rect, where is it?

Tags: c#, rect

This drives me crazy, creating new **console** application project, then

```
// adding it as reference of course
using System.Windows;

// somewhere in method
var rect = new Rect(1, 2, 3, 4); // no Rect
```

> The type or namespace name 'Rect' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What happens with [`Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `using` doesn't add a reference. It "imports" a namespace from already loaded references

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I know this (see first comment in example). My mistake was not paying enough attention which dll to reference. I was referencing `System.Windows` and this is just not enough. And I forgot what namespaces can be [split](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24904069/1997232) into multiple assemblies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add `WindowsBase.dll` as a reference to your project.